# Python 3: some reversed if statement

Tags: python-3.x

In my textbook I came across this example:

```
lower = (lambda x, y: x if x < y else y)
print(lower ('bb','aa'))
```

So far I used

```
if_stmt ::=  "if" expression ":" suite
         ( "elif" expression ":" suite )*
         ["else" ":" suite]
```

So, this 'x if x < y else y' astonished me a bit.
Could you direct me: where in the documentation can I find this construction?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So they are called "Conditional Expressions" and you can find them in the [python 3 docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) a longer clearer explanation can be found in this [section of of the 2.5 docs](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions). I use it a lot for conditional assignment like:

```
level = 1 if logging else 0
```

Comment: This conditional/functional `if` is found in many programming languages (Haskell/Excel/Rust/BASIC/C ternary/Java ternary) by varying names, but every other known programming language orders both their structural and functional 'if' in the same order {conditional, true_value, false_value}, whereas Python's functional `if` is an odd aberration, falling into a niche class of inverted syntaxes (inconsistent with other languages and even inconsistent with itself for the normal `if`). So it's no surprise that this perplexes beginners: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Inverted_syntax